# BOOTDEVICE NOT FOUND AFTER HDD click sound

Tags: hard-drive, boot

I have an hp laptop (elitebook) ,
In details, i was teating my code that was supposed to retrieve some data from prtg server, then suddenly my HDD started to sound like click click , a mechanical problem for sure, so i restarted my system first, in reboot still click click sound, and i got the message
bootdevice not found
Hard disk 3f0
Install an OS on your hard disk.

It was strange as i have an nvme ssd and windows installed on that hard so i was expecting windows come up ?

I removed HDD cause i thought it might caused some boot trouble, but with only nvme ssd installed on the board i still get the same message bootdevice not found.

I checked boot order ( nvme is preferred), i reset bios configuration to factory settings, i removed the nvme from board and put it back again, it is clearly recognised  as it is listed in the boot order.
Still the same message

Ps. In diagnostic i tested the hard drive and smart test was passed.

Any help and guidance appreciated

Comment: Your disk seems to be dead. Use data recovery to try to save any data for which you have no backup, then replace it.

Comment: Which one?HDD is dead probably, but what abou nvme?

Comment: Is it possible that the boot code was on the HDD and Windows was on the NVME? You will need to transfer the disks to another computer to check, perhaps inside enclosures if you must.

Comment: Boot from USB, e.g., WinRE or Linux, and try to recover data. If the *does not* work, the issue is not in your SSD *or* HDD.